# Enterprise iOS App slow to launch

Tags: ios

I have an enterprise provisioned iOS Application for Testing & Preview. It's been acting strange lately, when deploy to an iPhone, it will launch and idle for a few seconds and then minimize. After the 1st launch, the later launch is OK. It's as though the App is trying to verify something on first launch.

I heard that this could be related to Mobile Provisioning file that contain too many applications. How can I tell if this is indeed the problem?

Comment: I have the same problem. Hope you solve your problem soon.

Comment: remove all code from  application_didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function then try. Check it there any call/code which takes too much time on first launch.

Comment: This is not an Enterprise issue. The root of the issue is your code. You are probably fetching stuff on the main thread when launching. Tripple check.

Comment: I've noticed this on TestFlight builds, but only occasionally, like you mention. I **don't** think it is your code, like everyone else is saying. I'm only 85% sure on this, but I reckon there's a network call Apple makes on app launch occasionally to check the enterprise certificate against an online source. I've opened TestFlight builds on dodgy wifi connections and noticed the delay being much longer than other times.

Answer (score 1):

- You would like yo create a build with minimal things going on in Application_didFinishLaunchingWithOption.
- Check your iPhone for update.
- Its certainly not a provisioning profile issue.

Either one of your dependency is trying to do that. else their is too much memory leak.

Comment: Doesn't make sense. the non-enterprise version in AppStore works like a charm. Don't you think the same amount of code being run?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You can run your app with `Instruments (cmd+i)` with `Time Profiler` from `Xcode` itself.

[image: Profiling Option Menu in Xcode]

This will clearly give you the information about the time consumed by your methods.

Also try the following things,

1. Minimise as much as possible the use of `-application:didFinishLaunchWithOption` method,
2. Check whether you use Background threads for fetching both from DB and server,
3. Avoid importing unwanted headers and also check for the classes you are importing in `Pre-compiled Header`(if you have one)